# Which one is correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Hello  I just wanted to know which expression is correct

Example

> I need to compress a document.
>
> Q: PDF or word?
>
> A1: both of them
>   A2: any of them

Which answer is correct?

UPDATE, based on comment:

> My questions seems to be a conversation, so the hypothetical person is asking PDF or word? And I am replying both of them or any of them...my questions refers to the correct answer ( both of them or any of them)

Comment: Could you write it more neatly, I don't understand your question.

Comment: It seems you are asking if the correct way to compress a document is with PDF (Portable Document Format), or Word ( I assume MS-Word).. If that is the case, then the answer is no. Neither PDF or Word normally compresses.. Both can take a simple text document and create a file 10 times the size of the original. That is not compression.

Comment: My questions seems to be a conversation, so the  hypothetical person is asking PDF or word? And I am replying both of them or any of them...my questions refers to the correct answer ( both of them or any of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is

> *either* of them

meaning you need to compress either a .pdf or word document and have no preference whichever document you compress.  If you have both a .pdf and word document then to express you need to compress both then

> *both* of them

is correct